# standardising a normal distribution

Tags: statistics

Online I have seen this and it's confusing me: [transforming a non standard normal distribution.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9k0Vs.jpg)

In function theory $y = f(x)$ has a normal distribution say, then $y = f(X-a), a>0$, would transform the graph to the right, but for some reason on that image, it has been transformed to the left. Does anyone know why this is?

$$Z = \frac{(X-\mu)}{\sigma}$$ is the transformation.

Now I see that subtracting the mean (say $10$ for argument's sake), will normalise it about $0$, so graphically it moves to the left, but still, function theory tells me it should move to the right. Where am I going wrong with my understanding? I feel like I'm missing something simple.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "on that image, it has been transformed to the left". I don't see anything that has been transformed to the left, on the picture ... The way that I see it, is that in the picture, only the width of the curve is changing.

Comment: sorry image is a screenshot from a video, and it seems I took the screenshot a bit late! The original image had the original bell curve on the right, and the new one to the left. So the transformation moves the graph to the left, but the video for whatever reason used the funtion notation with the minus sign, which indicated the normal distribution moved to the right. if f(x-a) and Z = X-a, where a>0, Z means graph moves to left, but f(x-a) means graph shifts to right. which is it?